# Validating fails because of account permissions

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I've been added as a Team member by Team Admin through the iTunesConnect and I am trying to create an archive and validate it. It fails as title says with a message :

[image: validation failed message]

Also, if I try to let the Xcode fix this automatically, I get this error:

[image: validation failed message]

The Team Agent created iOS Distribution profile in iTunesConnect and according to the docs, the Team Member indeed can't create certificates :

[image: privileges assigned to each membership level]

but that is why the Team Admin created them for me, but still, it looks like my Xcode tries to create certificates, rather than to download and use them (while validating archive). Any ides why is this happening and how to validate an archive and upload the build to the iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certs are always paired with private keys. You need the cert/key pair to sign properly.

Since your team agent created the distribution cert, the cert/private key is on their computer's keychain. Even if you were to download the cert, you'd be missing the private key. Your team agent will need to open up Keychain App, export it, send it to you, and then you'll need to import it into your keychain.

At that point, assuming you also have the correct provisioning files downloaded and have the build settings correct, signing should work.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I will try this. And yeah, I don't have a private key from his Mac (only cert). So that can be it.

Comment: So, it didn't worked somehow. I tried what you said. The Team Agent has exported his distribution certificate along with private key, and the cert is valid. Correct team name is chosen as well. Also, tried cleaning project / quitting Xcode, deleting derived data. Still nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct cert and key?  There are different ones for the development vs distribution profiles.  Also, can you show your project build settings?

Comment: @wottle I am positive that I am using correct certificate / key - that is the cert / key the Team Admin is using on his computer. He sent me a .p12 file so I have imported everything successfully. I have set a correct developer provisioning profile for debug, and correct distribution provisioning profile for release (in Code Signing Identity section, if that is what you've meant about build settings).

Comment: @wottle Remember, I am a Team member, not an Admin nor Agent. Maybe members can't upload builds to iTC.

Comment: Also, one correction. It is Team Admin who added me, not the Team Agent.

Comment: So it is clear that your problem is related to the certificates / key / code signing settings on your mac.  It would be great to see your cert in the Keychain Access app, complete with the green check stating it is valid, with a private key associated with it (you can expand the cert in Keychain Access).  Also, verifying that the build settings are correctly referencing that code signing identity.  One thing to verify would be whether the Team Admin has successfully built with his private key and cert.  It could be that his cert / profile are bad and he transferred them to you.

Comment: Also, the reason Xcode is trying to create a cert is that it has determined that you do not have a valid cert for iPhone distribution.  There can be multiple reasons for that and providing more details will help us track down the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Xcode is trying to create a cert because it believes there is something wrong with your code signing settings.  This can mean several things:

1. You don't have a valid iOS distribution certificate.  To check this,
   go into the Keychain Access app and check that you have a green
   check mark when you select the certificate from the list on the
   left.

   [image: ios certificate validity].

   If it's not valid, it could have been revoked on the Apple developer site, or
   it may have expired.

   Also, make sure you have the appropriate provisioning profile and 
   certificate by downloading them from Apple's developer site. The only thing 
   your Team Admin should need to send you is the private key.  If the private 
   key doesn't connect to the certificate you got from Apple's developer site, 
   you were given the wrong key.
2. You could have a valid certificate, but be missing the required
   private key that allows you to sign things with that certificate. 
   This is required to use the certificate to sign things, and will
   also cause Xcode to try to generate a new cert when submitting. Make 
   sure you can expand the cert to see the private key shown in item 3 in the 
   image below. [image: Keychain Access example of valid certificate with associated private key]
3. The project code signing settings are referencing a code signing identity 
   that does not match the certificate and key in your keychain.  I recommend 
   that you use the following settings in your project's code signing section.
   For `Provisioning Profile`, choose "Automatic". For `Code Signing Identity`, 
   choose "iOS Developer" for the `Debug` build config, and "iOS Distribution" 
   for the `Release` build config.

   [image: recommended code signing settings for iOS projects]

I would also recommend you taking a look at Apple's great video on [What's 
New in Code Signing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/401/) from WWDC that covers the key components of code signing iOS apps.

Comment: Currently, I can be positive about the fact that distribution certificate is valid, at least it shows as valid in KeyChain. About the private key, I don't know how to check if it is wrong or the right one? There is a private key when I expand the certificate. About other things, I will check as soon as I can and will let you know about the results.

Comment: Can you verify that the Team Admin who sent you the certificate can build and submit the app?  Having a valid cert is one part, but it has to be a cert that is tied to the iOS Distribution provisioning profile that is tied to the app ID.  That's why it would be best to delete the certificate and provisioning profiles you've been given, and then download the provisioning profile and certificate from Apple's developer site.

Comment: Yeah, we tried that. He can build and upload... I will be able to provide more information tomorrow. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: I have found one weird thing. In iTC I am not able to download distribution certificate. It is visible, but I am not able to download it. Anyways, team admin sent me that certificate, along with his private key. So will update with results shortly.

Comment: Also, having the Team member role only controls half of the equation.  You will also need to be added as an App Manager role in iTunes Connect.  See the roles here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24

Comment: Actually after we have re-imported certificates (and set provisioning profile explicitly) everything worked. Yeah, thanks for the additional info. I have been added not as an App Manager, but as an Developer.

Comment: Also, I am really sad that I can't split the bounty, because Ben is first who was first answered correctly. And you have provided an additional info and have put a lot of effort into this. So I will accept his answer, but will reward you with a bounty. It really sucks that you can't split up a bounty, because both answers are helpful and correct.

Comment: Glad that it is now working for you.  Code signing can be a painful part of the iOS development process.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've accidentally enabled the app groups (for another app bundle id).

Disabling the app groups in capabilities solved the issue