# Xcode automatic code signing distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

somehow i got the same problem like in this question: 
[Validating fails because of account permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826579/validating-fails-because-of-account-permissions)

We got a valid distribution certificate with private key and with the new automatic code signing in Xcode 8 everything works fine while developing. But when we try to upload an archive to itunes connect only a admin is able to do it. And for every admin we have to create a new distribution certificate. Normal Members always get the message: `Your account does not have permission to create iOS distribution certificate` even if a valid cert is in the keychain.

So my question: how do we have to setup Xcode 8 with automatic signing to work with one distribution cert, independent of the account role?

Comment: This is a really good resource for understanding the differences in Xcode 7 and 8's Code Signing features: http://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html

Comment: Specifically: http://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#building-for-distribution-xcode-8

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark w/o more info ... but from the (link I provided above)[http://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#building-for-distribution-xcode-8], check the section titled *Building for Distribution* under Xcode 8 and ensure you're running the "Archive" action rather than the "Build" action...

> In order to create builds of your application for distribution while using the new Automatic Signing method in Xcode 8, you have to utilize the "Archive" scheme action. This is assigned a build configuration in the scheme editor, and while that build configuration is setup to use the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` value of "iPhone Developer"; the "Archive" action will over-ride that to always use a distribution signing identity and provisioning profile. So instead of performing a regular "Build" action, you will have to invoke the "Archive" action. This will generate a build and bring up the Xcode Organizer window that lists all of the archives created by Xcode as an ".xcarchive" in the UI.

I would also triple-check that the certs you have in your Keychain are those for distribution. It is likely that the admin who created and downloaded them to their computer would need to send them to you.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. I have read this article before, but I don't know what to do with it. The cert is definitely valid, we uploaded successfully an archive with it, then exported it to the other machine. On the member account machine all we did was setting the team as well as the auto-sign option. We can create an archive as well, but the upload operation fails because of that error.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check the provisioning profiles. From Xcode choose "Preferences->Accounts->Your Apple ID->Choose your company team->View Details".

May be your local profiles are out of date. Right click on the distribution profile of your app, choose "Move to trash", then go to the developer site download the latest distribution profile of your app. Do not use Xcode to download it. I found Xcode may not download the latest profile.